# SQL Server 2014 - Different Table Interaction and SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum

To be short with text, I have a database where I need to just select top 10 best products, with highest profit in 2008. (I have a sample db)

I have one huge problem.

Here is the incomplete, but working code:

```
SELECT 
    [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactInternetSales].ProductKey,    
    SUM([AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactInternetSales].OrderQuantity) OrderQuantitySum
FROM
    [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactInternetSales]
GROUP BY 
    ProductKey
ORDER BY 
    OrderQuantitySum DESC;
```

Here is the output:

[image]

In the db, I have orders and products, so basically there can be product with ID 15 for example and it can have many orders like 200-300.
I summed up all the orders and grouped same IDs.

Now I need to limit everything with orders which happened only in year 2008, I add up another table and here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactInternetSales].ProductKey,    
    SUM([AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactInternetSales].OrderQuantity) OrderQuantitySum,
    [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[DimDate].CalendarYear
FROM
    [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactInternetSales], [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[DimDate]
WHERE 
    CalendarYear = 2008
GROUP BY 
    ProductKey, CalendarYear
ORDER BY 
    OrderQuantitySum DESC;
```

And here is the output:

[image]

So my sum of orders became insanely huge and I don't understand why...

I just need to use orders that only happened in 2008, instead of reducing the number of orders, it increased unbelievably.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because you are using antiquated join syntax. Don't use a comma separated list of tables. You have created a cross join this way. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Also, use aliases for your tables and don't use the fully qualified name in your queries. It is difficult to maintain and 3 and 4 part naming for column names has been deprecated.

Comment: I'm shocked that I still see the pre ansi-92 join syntax as often as I do on this site.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is a cartesian join, which will return **ALL** possible combinations of each row in the `FactInternetSales` and `DimDate` tables.  You're going to want to use an INNER JOIN as below, and the `CalendarYear` filter can be used in the join instead of adding a WHERE clause.  Being an INNER join, this will still limit rows from `FactInternetSales` with the 2008 calendar year since only rows from this table that have a match in `DimDate` will be included in the result set.  I haven't used those tables, but I'm guessing they share a DateKey column or similar column (i.e. column that would be unique in `DimDate` and relates to a column in `FactInternetSales`).  Use table aliases instead for the full names for better readability too.  A table alias is not necessary in the ORDER BY, as this column was aliased in the SELECT and the ORDER BY evaluated after the SELECT, thus the `OrderQuantitySum` name is valid here.  Your SQL will probably look something along the lines of this

```
SELECT 
FIS.ProductKey,
SUM(FIS.OrderQuantity) AS OrderQuantitySum,
DD.CalendarYear
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactInternetSales] FIS
INNER JOIN [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[DimDate] DD ON FIS.DateKey = DD.DateKey AND DD.CalendarYear = 2008
GROUP BY FIS.ProductKey, DD.CalendarYear
ORDER BY OrderQuantitySum DESC;
```

Comment: Upvoted, but use meaningful table aliases. [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: For an example query I'm not entirely sure that it matters since he's just helping the OP non of the aliases will be meaningful.

Comment: @EricBrandt good point, thank you.  My post has been updated with more descriptive aliases.

Comment: You are totally right, DimDate has a column DateKey that is unique for this table, but exactly A.DateKey give me the only error here.

Comment: Does FactInternetSales have have any columns with date in the name?  Maybe something like fkDateKey?

Comment: @Zane, that's true, but it's only an example query to us. The OP needs to be able to make sense of it if it's going to help, and good aliases (incidentally, the same aliases I used coming up with this same query about 30 seconds too late(: ) will make it easier to understand and apply.

Comment: OrderDateKey, DueDateKey, ShipDateKey… None of them is in DimDate though

Comment: Since you're looking for orders in 2008, I'm assuming you want orders placed in this year?  If so, use OrderDateKey.  DueDateKey is the date the orders are due and ShipDateKey is when the order shipped.

Comment: I can use it of course, but no connection with DimDate, then I will need to reverse join?

Comment: No the join can remain the same.  Columns names are just that, names.  The data within these is what will be evaluated.  Descriptive columns names just help the developer working with the tables.

Comment: DD - http://prntscr.com/lrmbqj

FIS - http://prntscr.com/lrmbx3

Maybe it will help ?

Comment: DimDate.DateKey and the date keys in FactInternetSales are all INTs so any of these will work.  Like I said before, you will choose the key in FactInternetSales based on the date that you want to filter, i.e. order date, due date, ship date.